# Additional table on 2 table with one-to-many relation

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have 3 table. A, B, and C.

A can have many B, and B can have many C.

So I made one to many relation from A to B, with A_id on B.

I made other one to many relation from B to C, with B_id on C.

All works safe and sound. Life is good, until,
there's incoming case where I need a batch insert, to table C. I had to insert B_id to C as well.

My question is, is it okay if I included A_id
 inside the C table, to help querying the data inside C, so I won't need to eagering the data from B before actually getting the data for A.

I'm sorry if it's a little bit confusing. Further edits for better analogy is encouraged if needed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay, if you know what you are doing and can justify it. This is called de-normalization. Keep in mind that if you change the A_ID inside table B - you will have to also update it in the corresponding rows in table C, too. If you find this inconvenient - then you should not introduce A_ID into table C and instead derive it by joining to table B.

Comment: I see, I just wanted to clarify that the de-normalization I did, is not uncommon solution or outside the best practices of database rules. +1

Comment: It is a trade-off - you are the one to decide whether it is worth or not. I would personally try to avoid denormalizations in OLTP and keep them for OLAP only.

Comment: My case is demanding the table A and B not being changed often, so I might follow the de-normalization, and I'm okay with the transaction updates on both table.